# Mapbox Animated SVG In Studio Without Code

Tags: mapbox

I want To add Animated SVG In Studio Without Code Please Share Me Some Reference I Tried To Search Google And Other Websites But Unable Get Examples Please Share some info Related To this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

You can [upload SVG images to a style in the Mapbox Studio style editor](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-svg/), but behind the scenes it is rendered to PNG (see https://www.mapbox.com/help/studio-troubleshooting-svg/).

So your animation will not be preserved or (more likely) you will not be able to upload your animated SVG in Studio.

If you are interested in animated images with some code, you may have a look at this example:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-images/

You could also try if it is possible to add an animated GIF or SVG like this:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/